# Split LineString with MultiPoint - Shapely

Tags: shapefile, shapely, splitting, snapping, pyshp

I want to split a LineString object at a MultiPoint object. I use the following code to do this. Among other things, I use the functions interpolate() and project() to snap the points onto the line and the function split() to split the LineString object. However, it does not work.

```
def splitLine(line, point):
    
    # LOAD DATA
    point_fn = shapefile.Reader(point) 
    line_fn =  shapefile.Reader(line)
    line2 = shapefile.Writer('./Data/SPLITLINE')
    line2.field('LINE', 'C')

    # CREATE MULTILINESTRING OBJECT
    lineList = []
    for srL in line_fn.shapeRecords():
            ln = LineString(srL.shape.points)
            lineList.append(ln)
    multiLine = MultiLineString(lineList)
    unionLine = unary_union(multiLine)

    # CREATE MULTIPOINT OBJECT
    pointList = []
    for srP in point_fn.shapeRecords():
        pnt = Point(srP.shape.points[0])
        pnt2 = unionLine.interpolate(unionLine.project(pnt))
        pointList.append(pnt2)
    multiPoint = MultiPoint(pointList)

    # SPLIT LINE
    splitList = []
    splits = split(unionLine, multiPoint)
    for coll in splits:
        splitList.append(coll)

    # CREATe OUTPUT SHAPEFILE
    coordinates = []
    for ln in splitList:
        for x, y in ln.coords:
            pos = [x, y]
            coordinates.append(pos)
    line2.line([coordinates])
    line2.record(*'TEST')
    line2.close()
    setProj('./Data/SPLITLINE')
```

Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistake?

---

I found a solution:

```
def splitLine(line, point):
    try:
        point_fn = shapefile.Reader(point) 
        line_fn =  shapefile.Reader(line)
        line_out = shapefile.Writer('./Data/TEMP/SPLITLINE')
        line_out.field('ID', 'C')
        line_out.autoBalance = 1
        lineList = []
        for srL in line_fn.shapeRecords():
            ln = LineString(srL.shape.points)
            lineList.append(ln)

        pointList = point_fn.shapeRecords()
        while len(pointList) > 0:
            pnt = Point(pointList.pop().shape.points[0])
            for ln in lineList:
                if ln.distance(pnt) < 0.001:
                    pnt2 = ln.interpolate(ln.project(pnt))
                    pnt3 = pnt2.buffer(0.0000001)
                    splitList=[]
                    splitter = split(ln, pnt3)
                    elmList = [splitter.geoms[0], splitter.geoms[1]]
                    line1 = linemerge(elmList)
                    line2 = splitter.geoms[2]
                    splitList.append(line1)
                    splitList.append(line2)
                    lineList.remove(ln)
                    lineList = lineList + splitList
        counter = 1
        for ln in lineList:
            coordinates = []
            for x, y in ln.coords:
                pos = [x, y]
                coordinates.append(pos)
            line_out.line([coordinates])
            line_out.record(counter)
            counter = counter + 1
        line_out.close()
        setProj('./Data/TEMP/SPLITLINE')
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. The code you posted can't really be reproduced or tested because we don't have access to your data, so it's difficult to see what exactly is happening. Maybe try giving a small reproducible example and some visual aids of what you actually want your function to do. It might help give your question a bit more attention =)